# Trying to use AWK to remove a glob of text inside an html file

Tags: awk

I am trying to remove a glob of text, inside many files. This glob is inserted in the middle of the file.

In my bash script I use AWK to try and remove it.

The command is as so:

```
awk '/</SCRIPT>/{p=1;print}</script>/{p=0}!p'
```

where `</SCRIPT>` is the beginning and is the end.

The goal is to have awk remove, in the file, all the text beginning with `</SCRIPT>` and ending with `</script>`  and everything in between, and leave the top and bottom html untouched.

I have added a -x and a +x at the beginning and end of my script, to see where it is failing.

awk tells me this:

```
awk: /</SCRIPT/>{p=1;print}/</script>{p=0}!p
awk:                        ^ syntax error
```

SS64 tells me that:

> gawk' will ignore newlines after any of the following:
>
> ```
>  , { ? : || && do else"
> ```

So I think I need to isolate the "<" in my awk command, yet it's not listed as a troublesome variable...

How do I do this, and why didn't awk complain more like this?

```
awk: /</SCRIPT/>{p=1;print}/</script>{p=0}!p
awk:  ^ syntax error        ^ syntax error
```

Comment: There's a help button in the editor. You need to indent code blocks by four spaces (there's a button for that), and put inline code/html in backticks. Click on the "edited x time ago" to see what I did to your post.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `/` inside the matches:

```
awk '/<\/SCRIPT>/{p=1;print} /<\/script>/{p=0}!p'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to remove beginning and ending tag and all the text in between then you should use:

```
awk '/<\/SCRIPT>/{p=1}; !p; /<\/script>/{p=0}' file
```